# is Laravel framework stable enough for medium size project or should I stick with more stable Yii?

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii, laravel

I use codeigniter for most of my projects and I love CI, but let's face it, it's a slow-moving framework and it doesn't support the latest features of PHP. I think I've outgrown it.

I'm about to start a new medium size project (a CMS) and I would like to use a new framework for that.

I didn't want to use Zend or Symfony, so Yii seemed like the best option until I found Laravel, and I liked it very much, especially when I found that it has been inspired by CI, also all the praise on the internet helped too.

But what is worries is me that it has three major release in one year and I think version 4 is in beta release right now, and apparently developer team is consist of one guy and I'm not sure about it's future (I know it's open source and available on the Github but lack of leadership is never good).

I'm planning to use and support this project for many years to come, I'm going to release many modules for it, it's going to be something like whmcs but for a different market.

Should i stick with stable Yii or is Laravel is stable enough?  Is it too much work to upgrade Laravel to new version (in case you have already done that)?

I want it to be:

1. modern framework
2. mainstream enough to have a decent community (I'm sure if its right to use mainstream here!)
3. Low learning curve

Comment: Laravel 3 is currently the stable version and Laravel 4 is in beta.

Comment: @YousufMemon  thax , i'm going to use version 4 ... i think it would be easy to upgrade it one the final version is out

Comment: Yii ftw. Never heard about Laravel until some weeks ago, while looking for Performance tests in Yii, I never saw Laravel being compared. Yii uses the best things from other Frameworks, and it's really cool and fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 3 is rock solid and used in many many production systems. Laravel 4 is beta but about to be released in a few weeks and many people are also using that in production situations with out any issue what so ever (me included).

I'm not sure what you mean by lack of leadership - Taylor Otwell, the main developer of Laravel is very committed to keeping the software updated and is a very strong figure in the Laravel community. There is also a very active community of individuals who both offer support as well as contribute code to the core framework. So while its true there is only one 'leader', many people can and do contribute in a lot of aspects.

Additionally Laravel 4 uses Composer components for many of its core features, for instance most of the session, routing and core http code are actually Symfony components. Thanks to composer Laravel 4 is in a very strong position to stay current with any future developments.

Comment: thanx what i meant was , when a group of developers or company is behind some product  , it's less likely that they stop working on it in compression with one guy who solely decides what to do ... i know it's not very accurate assumption

Comment: Ah fair enough, technically there is a company behind it too - The company Taylor works at use Laravel for their main app and support its development: http://www.userscape.com/

Comment: and one morething laravel 4 will be officially released in May - 2013. so no worry go for laravel 4. because its learning curve is so small compare to yii and other frameworks, and laravel 4 is best for CI fans. :)

Comment: And now we have Laravel 5 stable release.

Answer (score 5):

Never stick to anything. The internet is dynamic, so the question should be:

- Is laravel the Framework of my choice?

Laravel 3/4 for CMS Framework? Yes, why not.
You don't know its stable enough? Many developer sends pull requests. Do it also and make it stable as fast as possible while create your cms project. :)

Originally I like Zend Framework and Symfony.
Laravel is not a performing monster but it is easy, light and flexible as I already feel in practice.

Comment: +1 for "Never stick to anything"

Answer (score -6):

If its between YII and Laravel, I'll probably stick with Laravel. Yii is good but Laravel can do better than it.

But personally I'm rooting for symfony. Its powerful and yet much less complicated to learn than Zend with symfony's proper docu

Comment: -1 for not providing details on why "Yii is good, but Laravel can do better"